# Intel XDK build for previous versions of Android

Tags: android, intel-xdk

I have just started developing apps in Intel XDK and was just wondering how to build an app for a specific version of Android OS. The emulator I select "Samsung Galaxy S" is using the version 4.2 of android.

My application works fine for Galaxy s3 but not on galaxy Ace (3.2) .

I could not find a way to add more devices to the emulator list.

How can I achieve this.

Regards,
Shankar.

Answer (score 2):

XDK supports Android 2.3+ so if you are seeing a problem on 3.2 it is probably a bug, either in XDK or your app.

Comment: I did notice that it says 2.3+ while you are building, I will try it on other versions and try to narrow the problem.